# Problem with email address in \href

Tags: hyperref

I have a problem with `\href`. I define an email address with `\newcommand{\Authoremail}{author@example.org}` but when I use `\href{mailto:\Authoremail}{\Authoremail}` and click on the link in the PDF, the email address that is shown in Outlook is wrong and has some additional code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `mailto:` prefix of the email URI is missing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\Authoremail}{author@example.org}

\begin{document}
  \href{mailto:\Authoremail}{\Authoremail}
  or
  \href{mailto:\Authoremail}{\nolinkurl{\Authoremail}}
\end{document}
```